# premailer - undefined method create_border_shorthand

Tags: ruby, rake, premailer

I'm trying to get the premailer gem working by following [these instructions](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer)

I've setup my project by adding a gemfile to my folder and a rake file to run premailer.

My rake file looks like this -

```
task :default do
require 'premailer'

premailer = Premailer.new('email_source.html', :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::SAFE)

# Write the HTML output
fout = File.open("output.html", "w")
fout.puts premailer.to_inline_css
fout.close

# Write the plain-text output
fout = File.open("ouput.txt", "w")
fout.puts premailer.to_plain_text
fout.close

# Output any CSS warnings
premailer.warnings.each do |w|
  puts "#{w[:message]} (#{w[:level]}) may not render properly in #{w[:clients]}"
end
end
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
undefined method `create_border_shorthand!' for #<CssParser::RuleSet:0x00000101533278>
```

I've found this [bug closed report on github](https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/issues/97) but I'm not sure if that's the route of my problem.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Bundler (ie. do you have a Gemfile)?

If so, try adding this:
gem 'css_parser', '1.2.5'

Then bundle install and try again. That will rule out the problem on the github issue report.

Comment: I had the following issue - The bundle currently has css_parser locked at 1.1.9.
Try running `bundle update css_parser`. Which I did and it fixed it. Thanks v much